# Generic query method based of an object from its model class

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

In my model class, I want to create a generic method say `get_list(obj)` which accept an argument of its object which contains values of their corresponding attribute, and returns all appropriate records that match with corresponding column.

Suppose that I have a users class in my model, and to use the `get_list(obj)` method. I just need to pass an object of users with its values. Obviously, this will save a lot of time instead of creating repetitive `filter_by()`.

```
class Users(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, autoincrement=True)
    username = Column(String(200), nullable=False)
    password = Column(String(200))
    email = Column(String(200), nullable=False, unique=True)

    def as_query(self):
        query = []
        for c in self.__table__.columns:
            if getattr(self, c.name) is not None:
                query.append(c.name+'='+str(getattr(self, c.name)))
        return ' and '.join(query)

    @classmethod
    def get_list(cls, statement):
        return cls.query.filter_by(statement).all()
```

To use the method, we can expect something more like this

```
    user = Users(username='admin')
    results = Users.get_list(user.as_query()) # result as a list
```

I'm aware that we can achieve the same thing with just write the query into `filter_by` instead of creating a meaningless object. However, in one of my APIs the object will be created automatically-meaning it will be automatic on the fly.

However, this solution is only a hack to just flatten the attribute and its value into `filter_by()` statement and obviously not working?
Do you have a better solution for this?

Comment: `filter_by` expects keyword arguments, where keys map to model attributes. You're passing it a single positional argument. Did you mean to use `filter()`? And "the code above is just not working" is not a proper problem statement (somewhat related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Finally, building SQL strings manually when using SQLAlchemy is most often the worst way (and error prone / SQL injection vector) to go about things, given that SQLAlchemy has its SQL Expression Language and all.

Comment: Thank you, it's now working. I don't think I'm using an SQL Expression. But, I got this warning 
SAWarning: Textual SQL expression "username='admin' and pass..." should be explicitly declared as text("username='admin' and pass...") (this warning may be suppressed after 10 occurrences)  {"expr": util.ellipses_string(element)})

Comment: Bad things will happen, if someone creates a user named `admin' OR '1' = '1` or such...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, If this is what you were looking for, but I believe with Python's dict unpacking, it is already possible to unpack all the object attributes to use as filter in the `filter_by` function.

```
results = session.query(models.Users).filter_by(**user.dict()).all()
```

You can also use the `or_` method to match any of the attribute values like below:

```
session.query(Users).filter(or_(**user.dict()))
```